# How can I add a new class for an Item in Windows 8 Templates?

Tags: javascript, css, html, templates, winjs

I'm trying to desing something like this with a template

[image]

But I can't I have this code in *data.js*:

```
var sampleItems = [
    { group: sampleGroups[0], importancia: "alta", title: "Item Title: 1", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 1", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: lightGray },
    { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 2", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 2", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: darkGray },
    { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 3", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 3", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: mediumGray },
    { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 4", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 4", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: darkGray },
    { group: sampleGroups[0], title: "Item Title: 5", subtitle: "Item Subtitle: 5", description: itemDescription, content: itemContent, backgroundImage: mediumGray }
];
```

When I try to add the new option to this part in the *groupedItem.html*:

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="item" data-win-bind="className: importancia">
        <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
        <div class="item-overlay">
            <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 291.08px;"></h4>
            <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the result is this one:

[image]

How can I solve it? I didn't add anything in the CSS

Comment: I think it can't be solved with a grid api.
but you can try http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2012/04/23/how-to-cook-a-complete-windows-8-application-with-html5-css3-and-javascript-in-a-week-day-2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First You need to specify the number of data items in data.js file for the group you want. then edit the groupitem js and css file as this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244627.aspx). You will find exactly  what you want